# Google query to find high reputation Stack Overflow users in your city?

Tags: discussion, reputation, users, google

How can I use Google to identify Stack Overflow users in a city with a reputation higher than X?

I can get a list of Stack Overflow users in a city by doing a simple Google query such as the following:

> site:stackoverflow.com/users Singapore

Any ideas on how to enhance this query to rank by reputation or filter out all ratings below a certain amount?

Answer (score 12):

You can use [such SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/470166/get-users-by-location):

```sql
SELECT TOP(200) Id As [User Link], WebsiteURL, Reputation, [Location]
FROM users 
WHERE Location LIKE '%Singapore%' 
    AND Reputation > '500'
ORDER BY Reputation DESC
```

In this example, you're looking for those over 500 rep.

Comment: What happened to this?  I would like to find a great home improvement person in my area by querying diy.stackexchange.com but I can't.

Comment: @Carson fixed now.